# right-arrow in #define state in QtCreator

Tags: c, c++11, macros, qt-creator

In my qtcreator, I incidentally found there is a right arrow in the macro define statement. I have never seen this kind of macro declaration and some others macro declaration dose not have.Like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7f4j.png)

I was really confused, could you give a more specific explanation or give some links about this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hehe ;) This is probably just a visualization for a `TAB` (tabulator), as opposed to space(s) (denoted by dots)

Comment: The tabulator has been indicated by the ellipsis. So I'm confused....